# Remove IUTableView Separator Using Custom TableCell in MonoDevelop

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitableview

Ok, I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the separator or set the background color for a custom UITableCell using MonoDevelop. I'm sure that I'm setting some value somewhere that is overriding my attempts, but I'm clueless as to where that may be.

I've tried following the linked questions to no avail:

- [Unwanted Tablecells showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391615/unwanted-tablecells-showing)
- [Remove separator in grouped UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358287/remove-separator-in-grouped-uitableview)
- [Is it possible to remove the black line which separates the rows in a tablecell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727460/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-black-line-which-separates-the-rows-in-a-tablecell)
- [Remove separator in grouped UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358287/remove-separator-in-grouped-uitableview)
- [Can I force a UITableView to hide the separator between empty cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633966/can-i-force-a-uitableview-to-hide-the-separator-between-empty-cells)
- [Eliminate extra separators below UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk)

In a nutshell, I've a custom class that inherits from UITableViewCell. In that class using the IB I've set the background color to RGB(235, 240, 242). I've also a storyboard that has a custom class that inherits from UITableViewController where in the IB I set the separator style to none and the separator color to Clear. I also set the background color to RGB(235, 240, 242). Despite this, I keep seeing a background color of white for the table cells with a separator between each cell.

I next tried setting the background color in the UITableViewCell constructor. I've also tried setting the separator and background in the UITableViewController class as well:

```
public partial class NavTableViewController : UITableViewController
{

...

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        this.TableView.SeparatorColor = UIColor.Clear;
        this.TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        this.TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(235, 240, 242);
    } // ViewDidLoad
```

**EDIT**
Below are some screenshots of what I'm currently getting along with the IB settings. I guess I should also mention (though I don't see how this would affect anything) that the Table View Controller is inside of a View Container.

[image: Results]

[image: Table View Configuration]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the result you are getting?

Comment: You can find a screenshot [here](http://imgur.com/CxfWIOV). I've also added screenshots of the IB [here](http://imgur.com/4okOa0j).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that moving the code from `ViewDidLoad` to `ViewWillAppear` inside the custom `UIViewTableController` fixed the issue. It didn't seem to matter what the `UITableViewStyle` used (Plain or Grouped). The only caveat is that there was still left a 1 pixel border between the cells with the color of the background of the table, but for my purposes that is okay.

Answer (score 0):

It only works if the Table is UITableViewStyle.Grouped.

I've seen the behavior you are seeing (setting the background color)

Comment: I tried setting the Table View style to "Grouped" in the IB, but I get the same results. :-/

Comment: Interestingly, if I move the code from `ViewDidLoad` to `ViewDidAppear` it seems to be working.